# How to update the value from one model field in to value of another model field in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, model

I want to update `Contract_bills_amount` field value in `Class Contract` from  `bills_mount` field value in `Class Bills`:

```
#Contract

class Contract(models.Model):

    
    Contract_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Contract_rec = models.DateTimeField('contract date ')
    Contract_total_amount = models.FloatField('total amount')
    Contract_deposit= models.FloatField('deposit')
    Contract_remainder_amount=models.FloatField('Contract remainder amount',null=True,blank=True)
    Contract_bills_amount=models.FloatField('bills_amount',null=True,blank=True)
    Contract_owner = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Contract_car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        
        a=self.Contract_total_amount
        b=self.Contract_deposit
        
        self.Contract_remainder_amount=a-b
        super(Contract,self).save(*args,**kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
            return self.Contract_code


#Bills

class bills(models.Model):

    bills_Contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Contract_owner = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bills_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Contract_rec = models.DateTimeField('date')
    bills_mount= models.FloatField('amount')




    def __str__(self):
            return self.bills_code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a foreign key relationship between **Contract** and **Bills** as "`bills_Contract`".  What else are you looking for?  You only need to reference the value of the related table.

Example:

```
one_contract = Contract.objects.get(pk=1) #get the first contract
all_bills = one_contract.bills_set.all() #get all the bills in the first contract
desired_bill = all_bills.filter(bills_mount=400) #get bills amounting to 400
```

So, you may not need the "`Contract_bills_amount`" field in **Contracts** at all since you can already access that through backward relationship.

I see you have a reference to the **Client** in both **Contract** and **Bills** (perhaps for convenience but that cyclic reference is not necessary since the Contract Models identifies the owner.)

This relationship (i.e  `Bill --> Contract --> Client`) implies that you also get the Bill from the client, like so:  `Bill <-- Contract <-- Client`.

You need to learn more about referencing related objects in django